# "ld -Ttext 0x10000 --oformat=binary loader.o -o loader.bin" not work

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

i am writing a bootloader, and encountered a strange problem.

my env: Linux chen-pc 4.15.0-30deepin-generic #31 SMP Fri Nov 30 04:29:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

loader.s from [here](https://github.com/yifengyou/The-design-and-implementation-of-a-64-bit-os/blob/master/code/c03/3/loader.asm):

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.code16
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, 0x00
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    jmp $
```

log:

```sh
$ ld -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary loader.o -o loader.bin # it words
$ ld -Ttext 0x10000 --oformat=binary loader.o -o loader.bin # get an error
loader.o: In function `_start':
```

why? what different?

Comment: What error? Your output cuts off before the error message.  Oh, `0x10000` doesn't fit in 16 bits so it's an impossible offset for a 16-bit `seg:off` address.  LD might complain about that even though your code has no absolute symbol references.

Comment: I suppose 16 bit jumps don't go paste the 64k mark.  But we'll never know unless OP posts the full error message.

Comment: @PeterCordes `-Ttext 0x10000` is over 1M?  `0x10000` is not 64k? gas does not have nasm's ".org", how do i fix this error?

Comment: The offset part is just the 64k 2nd part of a `seg:off` address.  You can't use `org 0x10000` in NASM either, and it doesn't make sense for code that will execute in 16-bit mode with code fetch from CS:IP, not CS:EIP.

Comment: ```x86asm
.text
.globl _start
_start:
    jmp Label_Start

gdt:
LABEL_GDT:  .int 0,0
LABEL_DESC_CODE32: .int 0x0000FFFF,0x00CF9A00
LABEL_DESC_DATA32: .int 0x0000FFFF,0x00CF9200

.equ GdtLen, . - LABEL_GDT
GdtPtr: .word GdtLen -1
        .int gdt + 0x10000 # address gdt

.equ SelectorData32, LABEL_DESC_DATA32 - LABEL_GDT
...
```

`.int gdt + 0x10000`,  a fixed offset is used. Is there a  better approach?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you very much for your reply, and i want to know anther. The code format is wrong, right code is [here](https://github.com/meilihao/write_os/blob/master/1.bootloader/3.loader/loader.s),how to avoid hard code 0x10000?